# Is it better value for money to part-exchange my laptop for one with double the RAM and touchscreen than to upgrade the RAM of my current one?

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, memory, cpu

I currently have a Compaq Windows 8.1 laptop with 4GB of RAM and an Intel-core I3 proccessor with 2.30GHz of CPU (and 400 gb of HDD). This cost me £359 at PC World back in August of 2013.

**However, I have a dilemma:**

At my local computer shop they have a deal for a £350 touch screen windows 8.1 laptop with 1TB of hard disk, 8 GB of RAM and an Intel-Core i3/i5 processor (i'm not sure).

I have about **£169** in my debit card.

What option would be the most value for money?

A: Purchase the other laptop using my current one as part-exchange, or
B: Upgrade the RAM on my current laptop to 8 or 12GB.

The second option would be cheaper, but the first seems more desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, there seems little benefit to replacing one i3 laptop with another even though the other has a touch screen. Do you really need that? Certainly though, the extra disk space might be nice. But again, are you short os space?

Next question is how much you would get for the old laptop? We can't answer that & I've no idea whether you would get anywhere near enough. You certainly couldn't expect to get more than 1/2 the original value & maybe a lot less if the laptop was originally discounted because it was end of line (a PC World favourite trick).

Looking at the extra RAM issue, you'd want to check that you were running a 64-bit version of Windows otherwise there is no point in upgrading the RAM. You would see little benefit.

Bottom line is, check how much you would get for the old laptop. That might force your hand anyway. Check if your version of Windows is 64-bit. Decide whether you really need the touch screen and/or extra disk space. Also confirm whether the new laptop is i3 or i5.

I have to say that a touch screen laptop, 8GB RAM and 1TB disk is likely to be i3 given the price. If not, it is either a bargain or something else is going on - though you didn't say if it was 2nd hand? At new prices, an i5 at this spec. would be more like £5-600 or more.

Comment: I've decided to just upgrade the RAM because whilst using a touch screen laptop I become addicted to the touch screen